# invalid character in class in regular expression

Tags: html

I am sorry for asking this question. But I can't find a working solultion and was hoping that someone here has a solution.

I am using this patern. But i get this error

`Kan <input pattern='[*$&%^#@!()-_*+A-Za-z0-9]+'> niet controleren, omdat het patroon geen geldige regexp is: invalid character in class in regular expression`

Comment: Why do you have multiple asterisk `*` tokens in your character class? What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `()` and `-`.

```
<input pattern='[*$&%^#@!\(\)\-_*+A-Za-z0-9]+'>
```

Comment: +1 - this is very obvious when [using the proper flags on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YlNtZS/1) when accounting for the fact that V8 (and likely other JavaScript engines) now add the `v` flag by default, which makes unescaped `(`, `)`, and `-` tokens (probably among others) invalid members of a character class.

Comment: Great! [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions) can also be useful to visitors to this answer.